# When I try to compile a program written in flutter it gives an error (I'm using fedora linux 36)

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors, fedora

`Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode... /snap/flutter/current/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:1116:1: error: cannot use dot operator on a type /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:6: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:13: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:15: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:31: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:45: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:47: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:54: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:61: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:63: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:79: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:1: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:10: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:12: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:19: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:25: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:26: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:28: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:44: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=] clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation) clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault (core dumped) /snap/flutter/current/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:1116:1: error: cannot use dot operator on a type /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:6: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:13: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:15: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:31: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:45: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:47: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:54: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:61: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:63: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:79: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:1: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:10: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:12: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:19: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:25: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:26: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:28: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:44: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=] clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation) clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault (core dumped) /snap/flutter/current/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:1116:1: error: cannot use dot operator on a type /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:6: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:13: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:15: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:31: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:45: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:47: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:54: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:61: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:63: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:1:79: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:1: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:10: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:12: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:19: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:25: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:26: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:28: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include/stddef.h:3:44: error: source file is not valid UTF-8 fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=] clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation) clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault (core dumped) Exception: Build process failed Exited`

I uninstalled and installed flutter but it didn't work

Comment: can you include `flutter doctor`

Comment: returns that there are no problems
[luvas@fedora snap]$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.8, on Fedora Linux 36 (Workstation Edition)
    6.0.5-200.fc36.x86_64, locale pt_BR.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!

Comment: does `flutter build -d web-server` works? I've also faced the snap issue, then installed it manually

Comment: didn't work :0, I think I'll install it manually, I'm trying to solve this in class, thanks ^^
the return was:
[luvas@fedora Documentos]$ flutter build -d web-server
Missing subcommand for "flutter build".


Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and
options.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.